# calculating ifa flags larger then 0xFF from /proc/net/if_inet6

Tags: linux, networking, proc

I have been trying to write some [code](https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter/pull/2340) for puppetlabs facter program to parse the [ifa flags](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.19/include/uapi/linux/if_addr.h#L46-L56) from  `/proc/net/if_inet6`.  currently the code works well detecting flags for values [< FF](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.19/include/uapi/linux/if_addr.h#L46-L52) but struggles with the ones > FF.  As far as i can tell all the flags should be encoded in the [fifth column](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/network_administration_guides/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/proc-net.html) of `/proc/net/if_inet6`.  however when i check on a server which has (i belive) `IFA_F_MANAGETEMPADDR` set e.g.:

```
4: private: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:0:860:103:4ed9:8fff:fe6d:a085/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic 
       valid_lft 2591992sec preferred_lft 604792sec
    inet6 fe80::4ed9:8fff:fe6d:a085/64 scope link
```

the flags(column 5) as well as the scope (column 4) in `/proc/net/if_inet6` are both set to `0x00` e.g.:

```
20010000086001034ed98ffffe6da085 04 40 00 00  private
```

is anyone able to point me in the direction to be able to calculate if flags like `mngtmpaddr` are set, either by reading `/proc/net/if_inet6` or something else in procfs (i would prefer to not parse `ip -r -o addr`)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own questions.  Even though ida_flags is a u32, the value is [cast to a u8](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/454859c552da78b0f587205d308401922b56863e/net/ipv6/addrconf.c#L4332) when printing to `/proc/net/if_inet6`.  this happened as some programs had issues [reading the new values](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1056711#c5).

I have not found anything in ruby or procfs which expose the u32 flag.